# Dynamic Choice Lists in Forms

Tags: 2010, choice-field

What is the best way to accommodate dynamic dropdown lists for New & Edit Forms?

Example:  User chooses an option in dropdown 1, which then triggers specific values in dropdown 2.

Surely I don't have to use the Client Object Model and Jquery?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done in InfoPath or using jQuery and the [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com) cascading dropdowns function.

Comment: Your answer was correct as well.  Since you answered it first (pointing me to spservices), I'll give you the credit.

Comment: Gracias, it's a great little toolkit to have in your arsenal.

Answer (score 2):

A free downloadable plugin which uses jQuery and SPServices can be downloaded here: http://www.itidea.nl/index.php/cascading-dropdowns-with-jquery-and-spservices-on-a-page-or-webpart/

Comment: Brilliant example.

Comment: Thanks, if it's a solution for you, please mark the answer as 'answered'.